# Re-send e-mails from ASSP anti-spam mail relay server?

Tags: postfix

I have installed ASSP/Clamav/Postfix on a mail relay server. This is now the mail relaying server that processes all e-mail for spam and viruses and then forwards the legit e-mails to the real mail destination server.

This works flawlessly. However when we used Barracuda's for anti-spam, this has one advantage and that was the backlog feature. The Barracuda Anti-Spam Server saves all e-mail of the server and you can always chose to resend those e-mails. Sometimes if your mail destination server has downtime, this also allows resending e-mails and you have lost 0 e-mails.

Since ASSP is only a proxy server, they say that I should really see if Postfix can handle this. So my question is... is there software out there, preferably with a GUI, that saves all e-mail on the relay-server and allows re-sending e-mails from this backlog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASSP does have the ability to resend messages, although it is somewhat limited.  From the web interface, select "View Maillog Tail" from the left side menu.  You can browse the log or search for a particular address or string at the top.

When you find the message you're looking for, you'll see a line similar to the following:

```
2011-05-24 15:36:38 blahblah [Worker_1] [MessageOK] 1.2.3.4 <user@domain.com> to: otherguy@otherdomain.com message ok [RE Hello World] -> notspam/9341.eml
```

the part reading "notspam/123.eml" or "spam/456.eml" will be a clickable link.  Click it to view the message in a new window.  There is a dropdown that says "select action."  Choose "Copy to resendmail" and click the button labeled "Do it!".

This forwards the message to your MTA for delivery.  You can also copy the message to the spam/notspam log or delete it if it was miscategorized.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In postfix, you can set a Bcc for all emails. This recipient will then receive a copy of all emails, and you can replay them later if needed.

http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#auto_bcc